# Tailing MariaDB database changes like tailing the MongoDB oplog

Tags: mariadb, mariasql

Is there a way to listen for database changes in MySQL/MariaDB, in the same way you can tail the MongoDB oplog? I am having trouble finding information on this online. Perhaps it's only available in Postgres and not with MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

Plan A:  Turn on the "general log".  All queries will be written to that log.  Be sure to turn it off pretty quickly; else the disk will fill up.

Plan B:  Turn on the binlog.  That contains all "writes".  There is a program to display the contents of that log.

Comment: do you have a recommended way of tailing the bin log?

Comment: Perhaps it would work to use `mysqldumpbinlog` (or whatever it is called), but I don't think you can use it in a "tailing" setup.  You need that program to parse the file.  However, it can start at any given offset, and the offsets are included in the log.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`mysqlbinlog`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqlbinlog/) utility to tail [the binary log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/binary-log/). To remotely tail a server for changes, use the following command.

```
mysqlbinlog -R -t --stop-never -h <hostname> -u <user> -p  <binlog file name>
```

To get the binlog file name, execute `SHOW MASTER STATUS` on the server you are tailing. If you want to decode row events, add the `-v --base64-output=decode-rows` flags.

[`mysqlbinlog`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqlbinlog/) requires that the binary log is enabled. It can be enabled by adding [`log-bin`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replication-and-binary-log-server-system-variables/#log_bin) to the configuration file. The filename can be controlled by adding it as a value to [`log-bin`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replication-and-binary-log-server-system-variables/#log_bin) or by using [`log-bin-basename`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replication-and-binary-log-server-system-variables/#log_bin_basename). For example, `log-bin=my-binlog` would generate `my-binlog.000001`.

Answer (score 1):

For my project, I use InfluxDB to monitor things and plot them on Grafana. general_log is a good option but your space gets wasted due to that.

Here is a link that will help you out: https://dzone.com/articles/mysql-monitoring-with-telegraf-influxdb-amp-grafan